# How do I add a delay before this line of code runs?

Tags: css

So I have this line of code in my CSS part of my project where it makes the item invisible but I want to have a delay on it. So for example, these lines won't run until like 5 seconds pass because I won't want the item being invisible right from the start. Maybe someone could rewrite this attached code for me with a delay added to it if possible?

```html
#message {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You can help others help you by providing code examples that clearly illustrate what you have already tried and where you got stuck. This greatly increases the chance of a user being able to solve your particular problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animation delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536349/css-animation-delay)

Comment: @Jacob Did your problem ever get resolved or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you describe your problem your solution will not lie in CSS but rather Javascript.

You can do either one of two things:

1. Write a Javascript function that hides an alement after a specified
   condition occurs.
2. Write a Javascript function that applies a specified CSS style after
   a specified condition so that the CSS will hide the element from
   that point on.

**JQuery**

Some people prefer to use JQuery (only do this if you really need the library)

```
.... snip html ...   

<div class=".target">
  Some content
</div>

.... snip html ...

<script>
    $( ".target" ).hide(200);
</script>
```

Here `$` is used to select all elements that have a specified identifier in this case `.target` .  The function call `.hide()` hides the element, you can pass an argument of x miliseconds to delay the transition. (0 or none is instant)

**Native Javascript**

Native javascript would look more like this:

```
.... snip html ...   

<div class=".target">
  Some content
</div>

.... snip html ...

<script>
    // Hide element function
    var hide = function (elem) {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    };

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(".target");
    if (!content) return;

    // Hide the content
    hide(content);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the element progressively, you should use `opacity` and `transition`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#message {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity linear 5s;
}

#message:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="message">HOVER ME!</div>
```

Note you also need to some additional code to apply `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` once the transition is over so that the element doesn't take mouse events any more.

Otherwise, you could set a [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) of `5s` so that the `visibility` property changes after that delay:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#message {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: visibility linear 0s 5s;
}

#message:hover {
  visibility: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div id="message">HOVER ME!</div>
```